# how to disable an option if it's already selected (PHP - MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

i am working on a dental booking website. it's a school project and i am almost done. but i have 1 major problem and would really appreciate your help.. i have this booking page wherein the client can set date, time and service. on my time, i have set a dropdown for available hours. i would want those hours to be available per day. i was wondering if it is possible to disable an option if it is already booked for that day. i only have these..

i have a table called appointments. columns are ID, userID, reservationDateTime, schedDate, schedTime, service..

---

```
    <?php
    $time = array('8:00 AM', '9:00 AM', '10:00 AM', '11:00 AM','1:00 PM','2:00 PM','3:00 PM','4:00 PM',);
    ?>

    <p>
<label>Time</label><br>
    <select name="appTime">
    <option>Select Time</option>
    <?php
    foreach($time as $value){
    echo "<option>$value</option>";}
    ?>

    </select>
    </p>
    <?php
    unset($time)
    ?>
```

Comment: You need some kind of flag/boolean/enum in database to show that a particular time slot is booked. Then in html you can set disabled attr of option tag based on that variable

Comment: Others gave the answer below (use DOM attribute `disabled`). But I would simply not show the option at all. I think, that if the user shall not be able to select something, then he/she should not be confused with deactivated options and it also makes the list smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
echo "<option disabled>$value</option>";
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo" disabled>8:00 AM</option>
  <option value="saab">9:00 AM</option>
  <option value="vw">10:00 AM</option>
  <option value="audi">11:00 AM</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<option disabled>$value</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `disabled` attribute. A disabled option is unusable and un-clickable. This disable all the options (you will like to add some condition...)

```
    <?php
        foreach($time as $value){
           echo "<option disabled >$value</option>";
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $selects = $('select');
$selects.on('change', function() {
var $select = $(this), 
    $options =    
$selects.not($select).find('option'),selectedText = 
$select.children('option:selected').text();

var $optionsToDisable = $options.filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == selectedText;
});

$optionsToDisable.prop('disabled', true);
});

//to apply initial selection
$selects.eq(0).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

If this times are fixed time that you have to show then directly show in option

```
 <p>
<label>Time</label><br>
    <select name="appTime">
    <option>Select Time</option>
    <?php
    foreach($time as $time){

    ?>
<option value="1"  <?php if (in_array(1, $time)) {echo "disabled=\"disabled\"";}?>>8:00 AM</option>
<option value="2" <?php if (in_array(2, $time)) {echo "disabled=\"disabled\"";}?>>9:00 AM</option>
<option value="3" <?php if (in_array(3, $time)) {echo "disabled=\"disabled\"";}?>>10:00 AM</option>
<?php }?>

    </select>
    </p>
```

Maintain table to save appointment fetch this from table and check is it available if yes the show else disable it.